# Create/update objects with mongoose/mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, object, mongoose

The internet is full of resources for dealing with arrays, but often objects are a more natural fit for data and seemingly more efficient.

I want to store key-value objects under dynamic field names like this:

```
project['en-US'] = { 'nav-back': 'Go back', ... }
project['pt-BR'] = { 'nav-back': 'Volte', ... }
```

Doing this seems like it would be more efficient than keeping an array of all languages and having to filter it to get all language entries for a given language.

My question is: How can I insert a key-value pair into an object with a dynamic name using mongoose? And would the object need to exist or can I create it if it doesn't in one operation?

I tried this:

```
await Project.update(
{ _id: projectId },
{
  $set: {
    [`${language}.${key}`]: value,
  },
});
```

But no luck regardless of if I have an empty object there to begin with or not: `{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }`.

Bonus: Should I index these objects and how? (I will want to update single items)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using the original code snippet unchanged, but adding `{ strict: false }` to the schema:

```
const projectSchema = new Schema({ ...schema... }, { strict: false });
```

Answer (score 1):

In `mongoose`, the `schema` is everything. It describe the data you gonna read/store from the database. If you wanna add dynamically a new key in the schema it's gonna be hard.

---

In this particulary case I would recommend to use the `mongodb-native-driver` which is way more permissive about the data manipulation. So you could read the data in a specific format and dynamically add your field into it.

---

---

**To resume my thought**, how should your dynamic change happen :

- Use `mongodb-native-driver` to insert the new key into the database data
- Modify the mongoose schema you have in the code (push a new key into it)
- Use mongoose to manipulate the data afterward

**Do not forget to dynamically update your `mongoose model` or you won't read the new key at the next `find`.**

Comment: Thanks I was thinking about ditching mongoose, maybe I'll do that or look into dynamically updating the schema (didn't know you could!). Will update this when i try it